# What minor gods are linked to Demeter?

Tags: greek

I ask about those who would fall under the category with Triptolemus, whom helped Demeter teach mortals about agriculture.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a link to a list of agricultural deities major and minor on [Theoi.com](http://www.theoi.com/greek-mythology/agricultural-gods.html), which includes Plutus, god of wealth and good harvests, Bootes the herdsman who ended up in the stars, the Horae who ordered the seasons, and Macaria, goddess of blessed earth.